# How does Toggle View of RTE in Mootools work

Tags: php, javascript, mootools

How does the toggle button on mootools rte work, please refer to example on http://jsfiddle.net/cheeaun/NHBVa/

How does it go from html coded to the rte.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is in the source code?

https://github.com/cheeaun/mooeditable/blob/master/Source/MooEditable/MooEditable.js#L587-603

the textarea is always there but is normally hidden. the toggle swaps the display status of the textarea or the preview iframe and on preview mode, it exports the value of the textarea as the contents of the iframe, making it render.

it keeps state via `this.mode`. not sure what else i can add...